# Django - generate ascii_letters in a template

Tags: python, django

We can generate letters like this:

```
for key in String.ascii_letters:
     print key
```

How can we access these ascii_letters in a template?

Comment: By adding them to the Context??

Comment: You're not being clear. You're talking about an encoding issue, but it seems like you're having a regular template variable issue.

Comment: By adding to context we can do, but just want to know if its possible to access them directly in template.

Comment: I don't think so, adding them to the context is the more straightforward way I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method, as mentioned in comments to your question, is to just add the data that you need to RequestContext. However, if you need some data in all of your templates, you can use Django [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#template-context-processors):

```
import string

def letters(request):
    return {
        'ascii_letters': string.ascii_letters
    }
```

Then add your processor in Django settings. For example, if you put above code in a module called `context_processors` in your `app` directory, you have to add `app.context_processors.letters` to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.